# Query running slow and missing indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I am setting up some SQL views to be used as Power BI data sources. However, one of the queries constantly takes a long time to run, and I want to figure out what the best way to resolve this is. I am in the finance department at my employer, so SQL query tuning is not really what I do day to day, but I am trying to learn.

The execution plan is here:

```
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJGHe1W0H
```

I can see the execution plan is asking me to add some indexes, but I am not sure if I should do that or not. I have read that the SQL hints should not be followed blindly, as it could cause other issues

The query is:

```
select ansapbicalls.*
from ansapbicalls
inner join 
ANSAPBIStatus
on ansapbicalls.[Call Status]=ansapbistatus.[Status ID]
inner join ansapbifault on ansapbicalls.Fault=ANSAPBIFault.[Fault ID]
where ANSAPBIStatus.[Status Type]='Operations' and ANSAPBIFault.[Job Type]='RR'
```

And the missing index warnings are:

```
Missing Index (Impact 39.0531): 
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] 
    ON [dbo].[MXMSERVCALLAUDIT] ([TYPE],[DATAAREAID]) INCLUDE ([JOBID],[RECID])

Missing Index (Impact 51.6627): 
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] 
    ON [dbo].[MXMSERVCALLAUDIT] ([DATAAREAID],[RECID]) INCLUDE ([JOBID],[USERID],[DATE])
```

Comment: You didn't post the actual tables (or even the query). The execution plan mentions tables and columns that aren't included anywhere so it's impossible to know whether they are needed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience it is best to just try to apply the index.

Create the index by copying the code and name the Index, usually something like IX_Tablename_columnames.

Creating the index will take some time but afterwards running the query should be a lot faster. If this isn't the case (which I doubt) you can always remove the index again.

So run this code

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MXMSERVCALLAUDIT_TYPE_DATAAREAID_JOBID_RECID] 
ON [dbo].[MXMSERVCALLAUDIT] ([TYPE],[DATAAREAID]) INCLUDE ([JOBID],[RECID])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MXMSERVCALLAUDIT_DATAAREAID_RECID_JOBID_USERID_DATE] 
ON [dbo].[MXMSERVCALLAUDIT] ([DATAAREAID],[RECID]) INCLUDE ([JOBID],[USERID],[DATE])
```

And then run the original query again.

Comment: So that has halved the time to run the original query, which is much better! Cheers!